# Ubuntu Touch -Dekko email unreadable

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email

I have received two emails from a friend where I can see the email text in the Dekko inbox view. However, when I open the email it looks like it encrypted, but it is not. I am unable to read the email.

Any ideas how I can resolve this and read the email?

Answer (score 1):

I can't diagnose your problem, but may have a solution.

If you check [this thread](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg23415.html) on the ubuntu-phone email list you can see that development of Dekko as a click package has stopped. Your best bet for a resolution might be to switch to the snap version.

I'm afraid that I don't know how to change to the snap version - but someone else on the thread has asked the question so it might be the place to find the answer.

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu Touch version that supports snaps atm, this won't really help him...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. From what I can see, the only email client that supports more that Gmail is no longer supported by the Ubuntu Touch dev team. So now you have to use the snap version (I have no idea what that is). However, this snap version is currently supported by any Ubuntu Touch version. The question is, what is going on and what is a viable option for someone who was using Dekko to read emails from different clients (in one place)?

Comment: Also the funny thing is that the emails that I was originally talking about can be opened up all OK on my andriod phone using MyMail.

Comment: Hi Phil, I think the situation is as you described. There is currently no development of an email app for the current version of Ubuntu Touch. 


A snap based UT isn't ready and there isn't a credible ETA for when it will be -> so there isn't currently a a viable option for reading emails from different accounts in one place.